# Make changes to a website written in HTML based on the content on a text file

Tags: html, text

So I've been looking around for an answer to this, without success.

So I'm looking to have the text inside of a .txt file to be inserted in a line in html5 code, I can't think of how this should be worded so here's an example.

`<iframe type="text/html" frameborder="0" width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TEXTFILECONTENT" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

And is it possible to have it change every time the content of the text file changes?

Any questions please reply I'm sure I wrote this somewhat wrong.

Comment: Why does your iframe have a youtube source? Also, are you on a server that can utilize a scripting language such as PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IFrame's `src` should simply be set to the full url to the text file. In your example, replace 'TEXTFILECONTENT' with the file name, like 'MyTextFile.txt'. Then the browser should fetch the file and display it in the `iframe`. If your textfile is in a subdirectory, then add that to the url, like 'folder/textfile.txt'.

**Edit:**
You can add a link to your page that loads the textfile into the `iframe`. First give your iframe an id, like this:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" type="text/html" frameborder="0" width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TEXTFILECONTENT" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then give your link a `target` attribute, like this:

```
<a href="discordinvite.txt" target="myiframe">Discord server</a>
```

Now when people click the link the textfile will be loaded into the iframe.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm looking to also format it to this `<a href="discordinvite.txt">Discord server</a>` sort of, I tried different ways but none of them worked so I'm back here asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can!, u must create your HTML5 with Ajax. example:

1. Client open ur HTML5 page
2. Client get fresh text
3. every 3 sec. ajax synchronize your text file from server or other

this can solve your problem because if u change text then each 3 sec. client get uptodate text..

Answer (score 1):

just change src to your file.., replace 'TEXTFILECONTENT' with the file name YOUR.txt